# JavaScript: Calculating inputs (select input) and resulting a number

Tags: javascript

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7mbQ4/)

When I run select something from the drop-down ('room_type_id' and 'bed_type_id') it outputs a "NaN" (Not a Number). If I first select something from multiple select input ('bed_type_id') then the output results are: 52000, 53000, 53500 although the real values are 1000, 2000, 2500 as you can see in the HTML form in the demo above.

I suspect parseInt has something to do with it. parseFloat didn't work either. Any suggestions?

```
function jungi() {
   var room_type_id=document.getElementById('room_type_id').value;
   var meal_type_id=document.getElementById('meal_type_id').value;
   var bed_type_id=document.getElementById('bed_type_id').value;
   document.getElementById('total_amount').value = parseInt(room_type_id) + parseInt(meal_type_id) + parseInt(bed_type_id);
}
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/7mbQ4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use selectedIndex and options values:

Javascript:

```
var room = document.getElementById("room_type_id");
var meal = document.getElementById("meal_type_id");
var bed = document.getElementById("bed_type_id");
document.getElementById("form1").onchange = jungi;
function jungi() {
 document.getElementById("total_amount").value = parseInt(room.options[room.selectedIndex].value) + parseInt(meal.options[meal.selectedIndex].value) + parseInt(bed.options[bed.selectedIndex].value);       
}
```

Moreover you must wrap selection tags into `<form id = "form1">...</form>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Your multiple select has no value selected on load, so you're trying to do :

```
parseInt("")
```

Which results as Not A Number

Maybe you should add selected on the first option of your multiple select.

```
<option value="1000" selected>Breakfast</option>
```

You can also check for an empty string before calling parseInt